# Suspicious URLs being loaded after hack and restore

Tags: hacked

I had a site that was hacked (had Arab words on the index.php), and all files deleted, but database still there.

I used Fantastico to install a clean release of WP 3.1, and I still some something suspicious.  In lower right side of Firefox it says "Read www.clickcoupon.me". 
With FireBug and PageSpeed, I can see it's opening: http://www.clickcoupon.me/plugin/sources/clickcoupon.js and http://clickcoupon.me/plugin/sources/jquery-1.3.2_nd.js which both look extremely suspicious.  These are not part of the standard WordPress are they?

The site is http://cpanelvideocenter.com. As of the time I'm posting this, it is a default install from Fantastico.  Unless they hacked my hosting company as well, I don't see how these files could be involved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Verifying that I have fully removed a WordPress hack?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19696/verifying-that-i-have-fully-removed-a-wordpress-hack)

Comment: No, see my answer.  My question was much more specific than the general hack question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!  It was happening in FireFox but not Chrome.  I looked at all my FireFox Extensions, and found "Browser Enhancements 1.0" and "Browser Coupons 1.0"
http://www.webenhancements.me/.

The other URL was searchdock.me, and was reported as a "threat" here: 
http://www.threatexpert.com/report.aspx?md5=af6cc99d717c0daef65a9dafd6c45db7

I'm not sure when I installed these or why, but I don't think they were related to the hacking incident.  It was just that when i was analyzing the hack incident carefully, I discovered these "extras" that probably didn't need to be on my machine anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the same database, then the hack code is sometimes stored in there. The [pharma](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http://www.pearsonified.com/2010/04/wordpress-pharma-hack.php&rct=j&q=wordpress%20pharma%20hack) hack uses this technique. Ensure that you have a clean database that you're installing into also.

Comment: First, I want to make sure I'm clean with the default new database created by Fantastico.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the link with twentyten active, so if it only appears in another theme, clean that theme or replace it with a fresh copy.

Fix your site the right way: see [FAQ: My site was hacked « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked) and [How to completely clean your hacked wordpress installation](http://smackdown.blogsblogsblogs.com/2008/06/24/how-to-completely-clean-your-hacked-wordpress-installation/) and [How to find a backdoor in a hacked WordPress](http://ottopress.com/2009/hacked-wordpress-backdoors/) and [Hardening WordPress « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) and tell your host. Change all passswords. Scan your own PC for spyware. Some plugins might be useful: [Search for "security" « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=security&sort=)