# Auto post Spams on my wordpress blog?

Tags: posts, spam

i don't know what the hell are these spam links on my friend's photo-blog posts! when i publish a post, this texts shown there! what should i do? (sorry for my very bad English)
blog: http://www.bius87.com

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdSY3.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have malware, either by downloading a free theme with malware in it or someone exploited your site.

[Verifying that I have fully removed a WordPress hack?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19696/verifying-that-i-have-fully-removed-a-wordpress-hack)

http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked