# Malware in header.php

Tags: timthumb, virus

Four different websites got infected and been blocked by Google, and after a quick look, I've noticed this just before wp_head():

```
<?php 
#d93065#
echo(gzinflate(base64_decode("tVVNj5swEP0... (edited out) hH5m7L/5+/gM=")));
#/d93065#
wp_head(); ?>
```

I have cleaned the code but this reappeared after a few hours. Then again and again. I thought that timthumb is the culprit, but this happened on a WordPress without timthumb aswell as I've scanned it previously with timthumb vulnerability scanner.

There's nothing suspicious in htaccess, wp-config and the files everyone is talking about, from wp-includes, have checked all the js files, nothing, nothing, nothing.

**What could it be, how do I get rid of this?**

Comment: Terribly sorry to hear that your site is infected. Unfortunately, questions regarding recovering from site hacks [are explicitly out of scope for WPSE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#questions).

Comment: I know, but I was thinking this is a bit different. I kind of need any info on this, I can do everything by myself, I only need a hint or two as I have been doing everything possible to fix this.

Comment: Read the question and answers Ray Mitchell recommended. We couldn't add more anyway.

Comment: I've had similar issues. Be sure to scroll to the bottom of the files you mentioned you checked. The hacks are tricky and add a lot of "returns" or blank space after the normal code and where the offending code exists.

Comment: It seems to be something related to a security hole in WP 3.3.1. Apparently a lot of sites have been affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to hear. You may want to look through the steps and suggestions in this WP Answers post:
[Verifying that I have fully removed a WordPress hack?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19696/verifying-that-i-have-fully-removed-a-wordpress-hack)