# Username was changed to "admin"

Tags: admin, username, hacked

I suspect a hacking incident in my wordpress site. My username was changed to "admin". How to revert back my username safely? Thanks

Comment: ["My site was hacked" questions are off-topic here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but see the Codex page [My site was hacked](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked) for some starting points.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new user, make him an admin, log in with that account. Then delete the other admin and assign all of his posts to the new user.

But first find out how the site was hacked, and [clean it up](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19696/verifying-that-i-have-fully-removed-a-wordpress-hack).